# Separating out Red component image from an RGB image in opencv 2.3

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to get Red,Blue and Green component image from an RGB image in opencv 2.3.I am using vc++ 2010.

Can anybody tell how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

use the `split()` function.

For the reverse operation, use `merge()`;

Comment: Does the cvSplit splits RGB image in Red,Green and Blue component or just creates a grayscale image.I used it i think it is just creating a grayscale image.

Comment: karlphillip has a point saying I am just a juman reference, but... did you check the docs for yourself? They contain all you need to understand the function. opencv.itseez.com